# Keep First N number of rows and delete the rest

Tags: sql, db2, udb

trying to write a sql which will keep first N number of rows of a table and delete the rest. I'm have comeup with this sql but the its saying I can't use the count here. Please help me to re write the sql.

```
DELETE 
  FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE
 WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE = ( 
 SELECT MIN(B.PROCESS_INSTANCE) 
  FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE B) 
   AND COUNT(PROCESS_INTANCE) > 9
```

Comment: Which database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: You can try using LIMIT keyword like given below:DELETE 
  FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE LIMIT 10, 100

Comment: I'm using DB2 database

Comment: Which DB2? What platform? What release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works for you (with Oracle DB)

```
DELETE FROM
    ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE 
WHERE
    PROCESS_INSTANCE NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT PROCESS_INSTANCE 
        FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE 
        WHERE ROWNUM < 9
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use HAVING instead of AND.

```
   DELETE 
   FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE
   WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE = ( 
                            SELECT MIN(B.PROCESS_INSTANCE) 
                             FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE B
                            ) 
   HAVING COUNT(PROCESS_INTANCE) > 9
```

or this

```
    DELETE 
    FROM ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE A
    INNER JOIN ZZ_TEST_FINTABLE B ON A.PROCESS_INSTANCE= MIN(B.PROCESS_INSTANCE)
    HAVING COUNT(PROCESS_INTANCE) > 9
```

Comment: This does not look like correct syntax. Did you test this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify this for your table, but should work:

```
DELETE FROM myschema.mytable WHERE pkey NOT IN (SELECT pkey FROM myschema.mytable ORDER BY pkey FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY)
```